# How to change EJB Transaction timeout in Apache TomEE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, apache-tomee

A call to one of my Stateless EJB classes from an app deployed in Apache TomEE can take very long in special circumstances, and the transaction gets rolled back by the server.

How can I increase the EJB Transaction timeout in Apache TomEE ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anybody else needs it, after some research I found this solution which worked fine in my case:

The config:

```
<TransactionManager id="Default Transaction Manager">
    defaultTransactionTimeoutSeconds 3600
</TransactionManager>
```

added in the "tomee.xml" config file.

Comment: Where is "Default Transaction Manager" as the ID coming from? Does there need to be code to specify this name?